# Powershell Change text

Tags: powershell

Have a text file that I want to change in a certain column.

Example:

```
12345678901234567890
12345678901234567890
12345678901234567890
12345678901234567890
12345678901234567890
12345678901234567890
```

Change to:

```
1234567A901234567890
1234567A901234567890
1234567A901234567890
1234567A901234567890
1234567A901234567890
1234567A901234567890
```

Using -replace 8 is to generic, would have to be the 8th column so it does not change any other 8s.

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume each of those numerical strings are on lines by themselves, you can do the following:

```
(Get-Content file.txt) -replace '(?<=^.{7}).','A' | Set-Content file.txt
```

Since `-replace` uses regex matching, `(?<=)` is a positive lookbehind assertion that checks for the start of the string (`^`) followed by seven (`{7}`) characters (`.`) from the current position. The current position will be the 8th character (`.`). That character is replaced with `A`.

Comment: Perfect, what about an if statement if change when Column 8 = 8 and don't change if column equals Z?